# Pyramid of maximum surface area inscribed in sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polytopes

Consider a pyramid with quadrilateral base so that all 5 vertices of the pyramid are inscribed in the unit sphere. Which such pyramid has the largest surface area?

I would guess the base is square since for all quadrilaterals in a circle, a square maximizes area. I would also think that the apex lies above the centroid of the square base, but I cannot figure out how to prove it.

Comment: If the sphere has radius $r$, what does that say about the side lengths of the pyramid?  Construct an expression that represents the surface area of the pyramid, then use calculus.

Comment: There is some Pythagorean relationship that you can draw here.  Draw a diagram first and label everything you need first.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a little more hint? I'm puzzled because we don't know the base is square. The right triangles one gets come from the height to certain points in the boundary of the quadrilateral.

Comment: Well, you can _suppose_ that the base is not square.  You can simply use one variable each to represent the length and width of that rectangle.  But once you set up the expression, you will find that the symmetry will suggest that the base is square.

Comment: Thanks for your update. We don't know if the base is a rectangle. It can be any convex polytope with 4 coplanar vertices.

Comment: On the same vein, you can suppose that you have some quadrilateral.  You will maximize the surface area of the pyramid if you have a square if you can show that triangles will have a slower rate of increase in area compared to the base.  Of course, in showing this, you need to be able to come up with the expressions required.

Answer (score 0):

This figure may help you visualize the geometry:

[image]

Everything is determined by a single length:  the distance below the equatorial plane on which the four base corners lie.

Call the distance between the plane $z=0$ and the base plane of the pyramid $h$.  Your goal is to find $h$.  The area depends upon it.

Basic calculus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the nice figure. Could you explain your remark a little more?

Comment: I"m solving the full problem with *area* (not volume) and will post it in a few minutes...

Comment: I think I see how to do it. I will work out the details and post the answer when I'm done. Thank you for your help.